# Align text in one order

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a sign-in field that collects the user information. Part of the design is to have the label of the field on top of the input. The problem arose when I made the name input into two inputs (first and last name). Since then, I have not been able to add the label at the top while still making everything stay at the center. Any suggestion is welcomed.

```css
.feedback-data {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  /* top: 12rem; */
}

.name-form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.data-form {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

.data-form>label {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30%;
  left: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback-data">
  <form action="">
    <div class="name-form">
      <div class="data-form">
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off" required>
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
      </div>

      <div class="data-form">
        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off" required>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="data-form">
      <input type="email" id="emails" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" required>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>

    <div class="data-form">
      <input type="number" id="phonenumber" name="number" placeholder="Phone Number " autocomplete="off" required>
      <label for="email">Phone Number </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox calls your name, buddy!

```css
.feedback-data form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.name-form {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.name-form .data-form {
  flex: 1;
}

.data-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse nowrap;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback-data">
  <form action="">
    <div class="name-form">
      <div class="data-form">
        <input type="text" id="firstName">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="data-form">
        <input type="text" id="lastName">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="data-form">
      <input type="email" id="emails">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="data-form">
      <input type="number" id="phonenumber">
      <label for="email">Phone Number </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer but can you suggest to me how I can make my code work? I have more style elements included that are dependent on my syntax

Comment: Edited - with your HTML structure.